# Converting JSON that contains only 1 field of arrays

Tags: json, go

I'm trying to convert a JSON that contains only 1 field which apparently an array to a complex struct in Golang but unfortunately I'm not getting the data back, instead, I got:

```
{Result:[]}
```

Anyone knows why? (code below)

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Account struct {
    AccountId string
}


type Response struct {
    Result []Account
}

func main() {
    input := []byte(`{
            "result": [
                {"account_id" : "1"},
                {"account_id" : "2"},
                {"account_id" : "3"},
            ]
        }

    `)

    var resp Response
    json.Unmarshal(input, &resp)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", resp)
}
```

Comment: The json you provide is invalid. https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/bR6NG5MZyu6 invalid json, one comma too many, and also `account_id` is not gonna match `AccountId` so use a tag.

Comment: Lesson: **always** check the returned errors!

Comment: @mkopriva why do I have to use tag? I thought JSON marshaller is smart enough to convert "account_id" to "AccountId" ?

Comment: You can try it without the tag and see for yourself. But I believe it's only "smart enough" to handle uppercase and lowercase as the one and the same.

Comment: It is "smart enough" to do *exactly* what it says in its documentation - no more, no less: https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal "Unmarshal matches incoming object keys to the keys used by Marshal (either the struct field name or its tag), preferring an exact match but also accepting a case-insensitive match."

Comment: You must review your own work before asking any questions! Your JSON is obviously invalid.

Answer (score 1):

use a explicit tag in your stucture type.

```golang
type Account struct {
    AccountId string `json:"account_id, omitempty"`
}
```

If you are a novice, keep in mind the JSON size, if is large then use a stream library (jstream or easyjson etc),
other advice is check nullables or omit when they are empty anyway you can use nullable library like https://github.com/guregu/null

Cheers!